# Proof of $p\rightarrow (\Box (\Box p \wedge p) \rightarrow (\Box p \wedge p))$

Tags: logic, modal-logic, formal-proofs

I need to prove:

$$p\rightarrow (\Box (\Box p \wedge p) \rightarrow (\Box p \wedge p))$$

The system contains all *propostional tautologies* and the axiom scheme $\mathbf K$:$ \Box(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow (\Box p \rightarrow \Box q) $.

Rules are *modus ponens*, *substitution* and *necessitation*.

Thanks for help!

Comment: What does $\Box$ stand for? Negation?

Comment: @MathIsHardNoItsNot [Necessity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic).

Comment: @Charles Do you mind listing $\bf K$?

Comment: @GitGud Sure, no problem!

Comment: Do you have the reflexivity axiom $\square p\to p$?

Comment: @StevenTaschuk Unforunately, no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\square p\land p\to p$ is a theorem; therefore $\square(\square p\land p\to p)$ by necessitation, and so
$$ \square(\square p\land p)\to \square p $$
by $\mathbf K$ (and modus ponens).  Now apply $p\land\cdot$ to both sides and use the equivalence of $a\land b\to c$ and $a\to(b\to c)$.

Comment: great job! Thank you!